# $_post remains empty after form submission

Tags: php, forms, intellij-idea

The post superglobal variable is empty after form submission; however, get  works!

Here is the code:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
    <form  action="print.php" method="POST" >
        first name:<input type="text" name="Fname"><br>
        last name:<input type="text" name="Lname"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

print.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['Fname'];
echo $_POST['Lname'];
?>
```

same code works fine on my PC and print.php prints something but here on my Macbook $_post is always null after submitting the form.

I use IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE with Php plugin.

[I use php 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPuyE.png)

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: @hmtareque I can't use form's data on server side because $_POST is always null it is not populated by form's data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ is not mapped to the MAMP server. That's why php is interpreted but POST does not work. In order to map MAMP to IntelliJ use [this guide](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+MAMP+with+PhpStorm+IDE#InstallingandConfiguringMAMPwithPhpStormIDE-IntegratingtheApacheserver) which works for IntelliJ ultimate edition and PhpStorm.

Comment: I don't understand why I need a MAMP server for php to receive POST data.  I have a local copy of php installed (including php-cgi), and I configured IntelliJ to use it under Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP.  When I click the browser icon while editing a php page, the page appears in the web browser.  The only problem is that $_POST is empty.  This doesn't sound like something I need MAMP for.  (In fact, when I last worked with PHP a year ago, a similar configuration worked --- although it was IntelliJ 13 and PHP 5.6.)

Comment: @Zack That's exactly what my problem was. According to  [this guide](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+MAMP+with+PhpStorm+IDE) under the "Integrating the Apache server" title you will find out that IntelliJ needs to deploy your project to a web server and MAMP is a local web server that serves your web pages. IntelliJ is not a web server itself. It only uses plugins to deploy projects to web servers. The reason that $_POST is empty is that there is no one to serve as a server until you add MAMP to do that for you.

Comment: If there is no one to serve as a server, then why are the the other aspects of the php page working?  (I'm not being argumentative, I'm just curious how everything works.)

Comment: @Zack Because IntelliJ can interpret php alone even $_POST is interpreted but it does not work until it is served by a server because $_POST is a request method supported by the HTTP protocol and all requests must be handled by a server. You can find more about HTTP requests [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) and about $_POST [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)).